# Facebook authentication tutorial missing piece

Tags: facebook, authentication

For the past 2 days I've been struggling trying to successfully authenticate users into my Facebook app. What I want to achieve in the end is to retrieve and store the access token of an user.
The problem I have comes by following the FB tutorial for authentication: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Just above the Client-side Flow section there is a snippet of code which should allow me to get the current user. Unfortunately, I only get an error:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No route to host
```

Traced the error back to the point I can, and apparently there is an error on this line:

```
$response = @file_get_contents($token_url);
```

because if I echo the $response, I get nothing.

What is there not mentioned in the tutorial that I should be doing but I'm not because I have no idea I should do it?

Many thanks

Comment: remove the `@` from that call to get the error message on that line. [`@`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) suppresses errors. Most likely you have a wrong parameter `app_id`,`app_secret` or `my_url` (191 error...etc).

Comment: I removed the @ on the line but the error is the same: No route to host. As previously pointed out   echo $response;   prints nothing on the screen.

Comment: try to `var_dump`, also are you sure you have a valid `app_id`, `app_secret` and `my_url` parameters?

Comment: While testing it I have encountered the 191 error so in this case I believe this is not the problem. If the user is logged out, then I see the login screen and the permissions' one as well. If I echo the $token_url, the printed string looks right from what I can tell. If I var_dump($response) I get bool(false) but I get the whole string if var_dump($token_url). I believe I'm not doing something right regarding the file_get_contents command. Any work around it? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it got sorted in the end. Apparently it's a server problem. I tried developing the app on 2 different servers + locally (EasyPhp 5.3.8.1). On the 3rd server I tried it works for now (fingers crossed). Honestly, I have no idea why it's working now and why my local server didn't function as it should have. Well, it works for now :D

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve getting the access Token by

```
// Get the current access token
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

//And now echo the access token 
echo $access_token;
```